# Python web scraping - Where to begin

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to build a web crawler to gather betting data from multiple betting sites. I have some programming experience but I am very lost in the world of web pages, web scraping etc.

I have previously used Selenium to build "bots" and I think I could do something with that, I have also read some tutorials (`urllib`, Beautiful Soup, etc.) but all those tutorials scrape very simple pages and the ones I want seem to be somewhat different (JavaScript, perhaps?)

For example, this page:

https://sportsbet.io/sports/pre-live/category/kq9kajLnphopJwuwh

How could I get the events with odds, etc.?

Comment: *"Where to begin"* is not an appropriate SO question.

Comment: That web page seems very complex and js driven. Start by googling headless browsers and browser automation. Its possible that selenium is blocked by the website, so you might need to use phantomjs or something.

Comment: Not to mention the legal side: *"All content presented on the Website, including but not limited to text, logos, graphics, images, button icons and software is either owned or licensed by SPORTSBET. It is forbidden to copy, print and/or download any portions of material published on the Website unless expressly permitted by SPORTSBET."*

Answer (score 2):

I found  [**Web Scraping with Python: Collecting Data from the Modern Web**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1491910291) to be a wonderful book which doesn't assume any experience with web scraping and only assumes that you know the basics of python.

The author takes you through scenarios from as simple as scraping a basic, static HTML page all the way to Javascript/Ajax ridden sites which may have some protections against scraping.

In general, the book shows examples using the `Requests` module for downloading and the `BeautifulSoup` module for parsing the html.

It also gives an example of how to make your scripts use tor to obscure your IP address.

*Note that I am in no way affiliated with the seller(s) of the book; It's just that I have found this book immensely useful and it sounds like you will, too!*